# Formula to allocate with multiple conditions

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to get an an amount allocated across a few lots based on its rank. I managed to do this with the formula below (table starts at A1).

For apples `=MIN(C2,$B$10-SUMIF($E$2:$E$4,"<"&E2,$D$2:$D$4))`
For bananas `=MIN(C5,$B$11-SUMIF($E$5:$E$7,"<"&E5,$D$5:$D$7))`

Now instead of writing 2 separate formulas, I'm trying to expand this to do the same based on its group as well.

```
    Group   Lot Units   Allocation Rank  
    Apples  1.1 29200   29062       1  
    Apples  1.2 2000    0           2   
    Apples  1.3 3000    0           3   
    Bananas 2.1 2778    1136        3   
    Bananas 2.2 2211    2211        1   
    Bananas 2.3 5942    5942        2



Allocation   
Apples 29062   
Bananas 9289
```

Comment: What's in B10 and B11?

Comment: And in which cells do the formulas go?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this in row 2 and copied down

```
=MIN(C2,SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,A2)-SUMIFS(D:D,E:E,"<"&E2,A:A,A2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out.

```
=MIN(C2,INDEX($B$10:$B$11,MATCH(A2,$A$10:$A$11,0))-SUMIFS($D$2:$D$7,$A$2:$A$7,A2,$E$2:$E$7,"<"&E2))
```